# FTP stopped working on Linux server

Tags: ftp

Our FTP service from our server just stops working and we have no idea why each time

we get this error: Status: Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server". Error: Could not connect to server

any ideas where to check in server?

Comment: Got any more information, such as which service you're hosting? Eventually the distribution as well.

Comment: CMS: Drupal, Wordpress, RT’s-CMS, Oracle Fatwire
OS: Linux
Assets; images, videos, webpages, some sites ecommerce, some brochureware
Server: 1 dedicated server
IPs: 6 IPs currently provided
RT's current C4L server specification: 
• Intel Server
• 4 x 2.3 Ghz CPU
• 8 GB DDR3 RAM
• 2 x 1000 GB HDD -(RAID 1)
• 100Mbps port

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the server is actually running. Try to restart it using something like:

```
service vsftpd restart
```

You need to replace vsftpd with whatever FTP you might be using. See if you get any erros when doing this.

Comment: yes we think it was not working. thanks we are checking that now.